# using content-box to offset height

Tags: html, css

Being the default box-sizing mode all it has done so far is annoy me. Now that I think I found a good use for it though, I can't get it to manifest. Check it

```css
#container {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}

#textbar {
  position:absolute;
  left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  height:20px;
  background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}

#filler {
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="filler"></div>
  <div id="textbar">here is text</div>
</div>
```

So the idea is that the textbar should take 20px from the bottom of the container and the filler should take the rest. I figured since content-box is described as including margin and padding in its total width/height, it would subtract those 20px i gave it for margin from the 100% and effectively be 100% - 20px but no such luck, it still covers the entire container and underlaps the textbar.

Why is that? Also how else could I do this?

PS! don't want to use calc() from compatibility reasons.

Comment: Take a look at the spec for display: flex :)

Comment: no flex either, i need my IE4 users!

Comment: IE4?! You *must* be kidding.

Comment: I take it the reason you're wanting to do this is because you're going to be dealing with variable heights, right?

Comment: IE6 is dying, IE5 is already dead, Programming in 2016 for IE4?? What??

Comment: @gdgr yes, the variability is determined by the container size. j08691 -  yeah.. kinda. while I love all the html5 features, compatibility is king on this project

Comment: The simplest solution I can see is to set position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 20px; on #filler, remove the height, the margin and the box-sizing is also kind of irrelevant, unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do..

Comment: Although I agree with these two fellows, IE4 support sounds preposterous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using `position: absolute;` for the text box, I would simply do the following.

Change:

```
#filler {
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

To:

```
#filler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:20px;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I figured since content-box is described as including margin and
>   padding in its total width/height

No. With [`box-sizing: content-box`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#valdef-box-sizing-content-box), values of `width` and `height` only include the [content box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions). They do not include paddings, borders nor margins.

> [image]

To achieve what you want, you can use `border-box` with padding instead of margin.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#textbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
#filler {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="filler"></div>
  <div id="textbar">here is text</div>
</div>
```

The modern alternatives would be `calc(100% - 20px)` or flexbox.

Comment: Doesn't do what OP wants, See the `bg-color` on `textbar`